# Get specific model of a xeon phi

Tags: icc, intel-mic, xeon-phi

I'm trying to find the exact model of a Xeon Phi coprocessor i'm using.
I run micpinfo and this is what i get

```
    ***************************/opt/intel/mic/bin/micinfo***************************
MicInfo Utility Log

Created Fri Jan 10 13:09:40 2014


    System Info
        HOST OS         : Linux
        OS Version      : 2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64
        Driver Version      : 5889-16
        MPSS Version        : 2.1.5889-16
        Host Physical Memory    : 1911 MB

Device No: 0, Device Name: mic0

    Version
        Flash Version        : 2.1.02.0383
        SMC Boot Loader Version  : NotAvailable
        uOS Version          : 2.6.38.8-g9b2c036
        Device Serial Number     : NotAvailable

    Board
        Vendor ID        : 8086
        Device ID        : 225c
        Subsystem ID         : 2500
        Coprocessor Stepping ID  : 1
        PCIe Width       : Insufficient Privileges
        PCIe Speed       : Insufficient Privileges
        PCIe Max payload size    : Insufficient Privileges
        PCIe Max read req size   : Insufficient Privileges
        Coprocessor Model    : 0x01
        Coprocessor Model Ext    : 0x00
        Coprocessor Type     : 0x00
        Coprocessor Family   : 0x0b
        Coprocessor Family Ext   : 0x00
        Coprocessor Stepping     : B0
        Board SKU        : ES2-P1750
        ECC Mode         : Enabled
        SMC HW Revision      : Product 300W Active CS

    Cores
        Total No of Active Cores : 61
        Voltage          : 1001000 uV
        Frequency        : 1090909 KHz

    Thermal
        Fan Speed Control    : On
        SMC Firmware Version     : 1.2.3257
        FSC Strap        : 14 MHz
        Fan RPM          : 2700
        Fan PWM          : 50
        Die Temp         : 63 C

    GDDR
        GDDR Vendor      : Elpida
        GDDR Version         : 0x1
        GDDR Density         : 2048 Mb
        GDDR Size        : 7936 MB
        GDDR Technology      : GDDR5 
        GDDR Speed       : 5.500000 GT/s 
        GDDR Frequency       : 2750000 KHz
        GDDR Voltage         : 1000000 uV


************************/opt/intel/mic/bin/micsmc --freq************************

mic0 (freq):
   Core Frequency: .......... 1.09 GHz
   Total Power: ............. 102.00 Watts
   Lo Power Limit: .......... 315.00 Watts
   Hi Power Limit: .......... 375.00 Watts
   Phys Power Limit: ........ 395.00 Watts


************************/opt/intel/mic/bin/micsmc --info************************

mic0 (info):
   Device Series: ........... Intel(R) Xeon Phi(TM) Coprocessor
   Device ID: ............... 225c
   Number of Cores: ......... 61
   OS Version: .............. 2.6.38.8-g9b2c036
   Flash Version: ........... 2.1.02.0383
   Driver Version: .......... DRIVERS_5889-16 (build@localhost.localdomain 2013-03-08 17:26:26 -0500)
   Stepping: ................ 1
   SubStepping: ............. 0


************************/opt/intel/mic/bin/micsmc --mem*************************

mic0 (mem):
   Free Memory: ............. 7162.67 MB
   Total Memory: ............ 7697.20 MB
   Memory Usage: ............ 534.54 MB


************************/opt/intel/mic/bin/micsmc --temp************************

mic0 (temp):
   Cpu Temp: ................ 62.00 C
   Memory Temp: ............. 40.00 C
   Fan-In Temp: ............. 30.00 C
   Fan-Out Temp: ............ 42.00 C
   Core Rail Temp: .......... 39.00 C
   Uncore Rail Temp: ........ 40.00 C
   Memory Rail Temp: ........ 40.00 C


*****************************dmidecode -t baseboard*****************************
# dmidecode 2.11

/dev/mem: Permission denied

*******************************dmidecode -t bios********************************
# dmidecode 2.11

/dev/mem: Permission denied

*******************************dmidecode -t cache*******************************
# dmidecode 2.11

/dev/mem: Permission denied

******************************dmidecode -t chassis******************************
# dmidecode 2.11

/dev/mem: Permission denied

*****************************dmidecode -t connector*****************************
# dmidecode 2.11

/dev/mem: Permission denied

******************************dmidecode -t memory*******************************
# dmidecode 2.11

/dev/mem: Permission denied

*****************************dmidecode -t processor*****************************
# dmidecode 2.11

/dev/mem: Permission denied

*******************************dmidecode -t slot********************************
# dmidecode 2.11

/dev/mem: Permission denied

******************************dmidecode -t system*******************************
# dmidecode 2.11

/dev/mem: Permission denied

*****************egrep -v "^[   ]*$|^#" /etc/modprobe.d/mic.conf*****************
options mic reg_cache=1 huge_page=1 watchdog=1 watchdog_auto_reboot=1 crash_dump=1 p2p=1 p2p_proxy=1


*************egrep -v "^[   ]*$|^#" /etc/sysconfig/mic/default.conf**************
BaseDir /opt/intel/mic/filesystem/base /opt/intel/mic/filesystem/base.filelist
CommonDir /opt/intel/mic/filesystem/common /opt/intel/mic/filesystem/common.filelist
ExtraCommandLine "highres=off pm_qos_cpu_dma_lat=75"
Console "hvc0"
Include "conf.d/*.conf"
PowerManagement "cpufreq_on;corec6_off;pc3_on;pc6_off"


***************egrep -v "^[     ]*$|^#" /etc/sysconfig/mic/mic0.conf***************
Version 0 4
Include default.conf
Include "conf.d/*.conf"
Service fileperms 1 99 on
Service network 21 79 on
Service sshd 80 20 on
Service pm 90 10 on
Service blcr 95 5 off
Service mictune 99 1 on
MicDir /opt/intel/mic/filesystem/mic0 /opt/intel/mic/filesystem/mic0.filelist
Hostname "floyd-mic0.icl.utk.edu"
MicMacAddress "a2:21:34:8a:21:fc"
HostMacAddress "0e:8c:d2:3e:60:8b"
Network StaticPair 172.31.1.1 172.31.1.254 yes 24
VerboseLogging Disabled
OSimage /lib/firmware/mic/uos.img
BootOnStart Enabled
ShutdownTimeout 300
CrashDumpLimitGB 16
CrashDumpDir /var/crash/mic/
UserAuthentication Local 500 65000
RootDevice ramfs /opt/intel/mic/filesystem/mic0.image


*********************************lspci -mmvvkD**********************************
Slot:   0000:00:00.0
Class:  Host bridge
Vendor: Intel Corporation
Device: 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub to ESI Port
SVendor:    Intel Corporation
SDevice:    Device 4f53
Rev:    12

Slot:   0000:00:01.0
Class:  PCI bridge
Vendor: Intel Corporation
Device: 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 1
Rev:    12
Driver: pcieport
Module: shpchp

Slot:   0000:00:03.0
Class:  PCI bridge
Vendor: Intel Corporation
Device: 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 3
Rev:    12
Driver: pcieport
Module: shpchp

Slot:   0000:00:07.0
Class:  PCI bridge
Vendor: Intel Corporation
Device: 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 7
Rev:    12
Driver: pcieport
Module: shpchp

Slot:   0000:00:10.0
Class:  PIC
Vendor: Intel Corporation
Device: 5520/5500/X58 Physical and Link Layer Registers Port 0
Rev:    12

Slot:   0000:00:10.1
Class:  PIC
Vendor: Intel Corporation
Device: 5520/5500/X58 Routing and Protocol Layer Registers Port 0
Rev:    12

Slot:   0000:00:14.0
Class:  PIC
Vendor: Intel Corporation
Device: 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub System Management Registers
Rev:    12
Module: i7core_edac

Slot:   0000:00:14.1
Class:  PIC
Vendor: Intel Corporation
Device: 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub GPIO and Scratch Pad Registers
Rev:    12

Slot:   0000:00:14.2
Class:  PIC
Vendor: Intel Corporation
Device: 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub Control Status and RAS Registers
Rev:    12

Slot:   0000:00:14.3
Class:  PIC
Vendor: Intel Corporation
Device: 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub Throttle Registers
Rev:    12

Slot:   0000:00:19.0
Class:  Ethernet controller
Vendor: Intel Corporation
Device: 82567LM-2 Gigabit Network Connection
SVendor:    Intel Corporation
SDevice:    Device 0000
Driver: e1000e
Module: e1000e

Slot:   0000:00:1a.0
Class:  USB controller
Vendor: Intel Corporation
Device: 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4
SVendor:    Intel Corporation
SDevice:    Device 4f53
Driver: uhci_hcd

Slot:   0000:00:1a.1
Class:  USB controller
Vendor: Intel Corporation
Device: 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5
SVendor:    Intel Corporation
SDevice:    Device 4f53
Driver: uhci_hcd

Slot:   0000:00:1a.2
Class:  USB controller
Vendor: Intel Corporation
Device: 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6
SVendor:    Intel Corporation
SDevice:    Device 4f53
Driver: uhci_hcd

Slot:   0000:00:1a.7
Class:  USB controller
Vendor: Intel Corporation
Device: 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2
SVendor:    Intel Corporation
SDevice:    Device 4f53
ProgIf: 20
Driver: ehci_hcd

Slot:   0000:00:1b.0
Class:  Audio device
Vendor: Intel Corporation
Device: 82801JI (ICH10 Family) HD Audio Controller
SVendor:    Intel Corporation
SDevice:    Device 0022
Driver: snd_hda_intel
Module: snd-hda-intel

Slot:   0000:00:1c.0
Class:  PCI bridge
Vendor: Intel Corporation
Device: 82801JI (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Root Port 1
Driver: pcieport
Module: shpchp

Slot:   0000:00:1c.1
Class:  PCI bridge
Vendor: Intel Corporation
Device: 82801JI (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Port 2
Driver: pcieport
Module: shpchp

Slot:   0000:00:1c.4
Class:  PCI bridge
Vendor: Intel Corporation
Device: 82801JI (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Root Port 5
Driver: pcieport
Module: shpchp

Slot:   0000:00:1d.0
Class:  USB controller
Vendor: Intel Corporation
Device: 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1
SVendor:    Intel Corporation
SDevice:    Device 4f53
Driver: uhci_hcd

Slot:   0000:00:1d.1
Class:  USB controller
Vendor: Intel Corporation
Device: 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2
SVendor:    Intel Corporation
SDevice:    Device 4f53
Driver: uhci_hcd

Slot:   0000:00:1d.2
Class:  USB controller
Vendor: Intel Corporation
Device: 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3
SVendor:    Intel Corporation
SDevice:    Device 4f53
Driver: uhci_hcd

Slot:   0000:00:1d.7
Class:  USB controller
Vendor: Intel Corporation
Device: 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1
SVendor:    Intel Corporation
SDevice:    Device 4f53
ProgIf: 20
Driver: ehci_hcd

Slot:   0000:00:1e.0
Class:  PCI bridge
Vendor: Intel Corporation
Device: 82801 PCI Bridge
Rev:    90
ProgIf: 01

Slot:   0000:00:1f.0
Class:  ISA bridge
Vendor: Intel Corporation
Device: 82801JIR (ICH10R) LPC Interface Controller
SVendor:    Intel Corporation
SDevice:    Device 4f53
Module: iTCO_wdt

Slot:   0000:00:1f.2
Class:  IDE interface
Vendor: Intel Corporation
Device: 82801JI (ICH10 Family) 4 port SATA IDE Controller #1
SVendor:    Intel Corporation
SDevice:    Device 4f53
ProgIf: 8f
Driver: ata_piix
Module: ata_generic
Module: pata_acpi
Module: ata_piix

Slot:   0000:00:1f.3
Class:  SMBus
Vendor: Intel Corporation
Device: 82801JI (ICH10 Family) SMBus Controller
SVendor:    Intel Corporation
SDevice:    Device 4f53
Driver: i801_smbus
Module: i2c-i801

Slot:   0000:00:1f.5
Class:  IDE interface
Vendor: Intel Corporation
Device: 82801JI (ICH10 Family) 2 port SATA IDE Controller #2
SVendor:    Intel Corporation
SDevice:    Device 4f53
ProgIf: 85
Driver: ata_piix
Module: ata_generic
Module: pata_acpi
Module: ata_piix

Slot:   0000:02:00.0
Class:  Co-processor
Vendor: Intel Corporation
Device: Device 225c
SVendor:    Intel Corporation
SDevice:    Device 2500
Rev:    10
Driver: mic

Slot:   0000:03:00.0
Class:  VGA compatible controller
Vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
Device: G96 [GeForce 9500 GT]
SVendor:    eVga.com. Corp.
SDevice:    Device c954
Rev:    a1
Module: nouveau
Module: nvidiafb

Slot:   0000:06:00.0
Class:  IDE interface
Vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
Device: 88SE6121 SATA II / PATA Controller
SVendor:    Intel Corporation
SDevice:    Device 4f53
Rev:    b2
ProgIf: 8f
Driver: pata_marvell
Module: ata_generic
Module: pata_acpi
Module: pata_marvell
Module: ahci

Slot:   0000:07:03.0
Class:  FireWire (IEEE 1394)
Vendor: Texas Instruments
Device: TSB43AB22A IEEE-1394a-2000 Controller (PHY/Link) [iOHCI-Lynx]
SVendor:    Intel Corporation
SDevice:    Device 4f53
ProgIf: 10
Driver: firewire_ohci
Module: firewire-ohci



******************************rpm -qa intel-mic\* ******************************
intel-mic-gpl-2.1.5889-16.el6.x86_64
intel-mic-ofed-libibscif-5889-16.el6.x86_64
intel-mic-perf-data-2.1.5889-16.el6.x86_64
intel-mic-cdt-2.1.5889-16.el6.x86_64
intel-mic-ofed-dapl-devel-2.0.36.6-1.el6.x86_64
intel-mic-mpm-2.1.5889-16.el6.x86_64
intel-mic-micmgmt-2.1.5889-16.2.6.32.279.el6.x86_64
intel-mic-ofed-dapl-2.0.36.6-1.el6.x86_64
intel-mic-ofed-dapl-utils-2.0.36.6-1.el6.x86_64
intel-mic-perf-2.1.5889-16.el6.x86_64
intel-mic-flash-2.1.385-1.el6.x86_64
intel-mic-kmod-2.1.5889-16.2.6.32.279.el6.x86_64
intel-mic-sysmgmt-2.1.5889-16.el6.x86_64
intel-mic-ofed-kmod-5889-16.el6.x86_64
intel-mic-ofed-libibscif-devel-5889-16.el6.x86_64
intel-mic-ofed-dapl-devel-static-2.0.36.6-1.el6.x86_64
intel-mic-2.1.5889-16.el6.x86_64
intel-mic-ofed-kmod-devel-5889-16.el6.x86_64
intel-mic-gdb-2.1.5889-16.el6.x86_64
intel-mic-ofed-card-5889-16.el6.x86_64
intel-mic-ofed-ibpd-5889-16.el6.x86_64


***************************uname --hardware-platform****************************
x86_64


******************************uname --kernel-name*******************************
Linux


*****************************uname --kernel-release*****************************
2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64


*****************************uname --kernel-version*****************************
#1 SMP Fri Jun 22 12:19:21 UTC 2012


********************************uname --machine*********************************
x86_64


********************************uname --nodename********************************
floyd.icl.utk.edu


****************************uname --operating-system****************************
GNU/Linux


*******************************uname --processor********************************
x86_64
```

Answer (score 4):

From [this reference](http://pciids.sourceforge.net/v2.2/pci.ids), according to

```
mic0 (info):
   Device Series: ........... Intel(R) Xeon Phi(TM) Coprocessor
   Device ID: ............... 225c
```

it appears it is a to be a [Xeon Phi SE10/7120](http://ark.intel.com/products/series/75809).